# Select unique customer IDs for specific category in retail and discard the rest

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am currently trying to get unique customers who have purchased from a specific category only, for example,

[image]

In the above image I can see all the customers purchased softline, for customer 1 and 3 it was other categories including softline, but I want to select those customers who have purchased softline only and no other category, from the above image I just want customers 2 and 4 and not 1 and 3.

I tried the below code in pyspark,

```
to_be = ['softline']
not_to_be = ['beverages',
'instant foods',
'frozen & chilled',
'hardline',
'fruits & vegetables',
'dairy',
'cleaning aids',
'null',
'health & beauty',
'other',
'bakery',
'staples',
'ready foods',
'meats']

softline = df.where((F.col('category').isin(to_be)) & (~(F.col('category').isin(not_to_be))))
```

With the above code I am getting both the customers who have purchased softline and also the customers who have purchased softline with other categories.

Can someone suggest, where I am going wrong?

Comment: share a code snippet that we can use atleast

Answer (score 0):

First select customers with the softline product

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as psf

df_softline_custs = df.select('CustomerID').filter(psf.col('Category')==psf.lit('softline')).distinct()
```

Next, find customers with only one product

```
df_single_product = df.groupBy(
    'CustomerID'
).count().alias('count').where(
    (psf.col('count')==psf.lit(1))
)
```

Finally, join these:

```
df_result = df_single_product.join(df_softline_custs, on='CustomerID', how='inner').select('CustomerID')
df_result.show()
```